# jQuery select all checkboxes of specific type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I would like to have a script that automaticaly selects all checkboxes of specific type.
First type is language so i want with one checked checkbox to select all checkboxes that belongs to the same language group (i.g. English).

I managed to get that far, and created simple jquery script that does the job.
I placed language field from database to a class attribute so i can check all checkboxes that has i. e. English class or German.

```
$("#engSelect").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    $(".English").prop("checked",status);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xGTr/

Beside language field i also got size field in db, so something can be i.g.:

English Medium, English Small, German Medium or German Small

Therefore beside "select all English" i would like to have "select all small" which at the end could result selecting only those that are English and Small or German and Medium.

Dont know how do it, since im using class already for language, where i can store size field from database.

Thank you for help in advance:)

Comment: just use specific class(es) as `small` and/or `medium` http://jsfiddle.net/3xGTr/1/

Comment: You can assign more than one class to an element (separated by space)

Comment: You can select elements with more than one class by concatenating the class selectors (without spaces), e.g. `$('.English.small')`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y5pzX/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="English small" type="checkbox"> English<br />
<input class="English big" type="checkbox"> English<br />
<input class="German medium" type="checkbox"> German<br />


$("#engSelect").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    $(".English.small").prop("checked",status); // here small is a class in addition to English
});
```

be sure to type the class selector continuously... without any space in them... that denotes that they belong to the same element

Comment: but how than checkbox looks like?
something like this:
<input type="checkbox" class="English" class="Small" />

or somehow else ?

Comment: use space separators for multiple classes in html, but in jquery selector class names should not contain space in between them, otherwise they will be treated as child selectors

Comment: last question what if one of the options in size is Extra small, will it be alright if i say than class="English Extra Small" i mean if it wont also select all small clases?

Comment: for Extra Small use class name as extra-small ... they should be continuous without space otherwise they will be treated as separate class names

Comment: @user2668182 Please, read basic tutos to try to learn instead of asking other people... BTW, my first comment under your question pointed to a jsfiddle showing how to use mutliple classes. You obviously didn't make the basic effort to try to understand it...